# How do I find the the last letter in an array word to see if the next word also starts with that letter?

Tags: java

I'm just starting out with Java so I'm pretty new to this programming language. I've been looking at similar problems for hours now but nothing specific enough to follow that seems to help me.

How do I check to see if the last letter of the first word is the same as the next word's first letter? For example, the user inputs: Chocolate Elephant Toronto. Chocolate's last letter is 'e', which is the first letter of elephant, and then the last letter of elephant is 't', which is the first letter of Toronto.

I want to make it so if all the words correctly follow one another, it will print something like "They all match" and if not, then "*second word* does not follow *first word*".

I'm just looking for tips on how to do this if the user decides to enter a different amount of words each time to check. I'm guessing I'll need a String Array, but can I still solve this using charAt?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlow. In order to get good answers it is wise to post code you have so far and indicate at what point surprising things happen. Your question is too broad to get a - for you - acceptable answer.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What exactly was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public String checkWords(String phrase){
    if(phrase == null){
        return "Phrase must not be null";
    }
    String[] words = phrase.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    if(words.length < 2){
        return "At least 2 words!";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (words.length - 1); i++) {
        String firstWord = words[i].trim();
        char firstWordlastLetter = firstWord.charAt(firstWord.length()-1);
        String secondWord = words[i+1].trim();
        char secondWordFirstLetter = secondWord.charAt(0);
        if(firstWordlastLetter!=secondWordFirstLetter){
            return String.format("Word %d does not follow word %d", i+1, i);
        }
    }

    return "They all match";
}
```

Comment: String[] words = phrase != null ? phrase.toLowerCase().split(" ") : "";
There was an error on this line indicating that there is a type mismatch

Comment: I've edited. Seems like you were passing null to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method like the following:

```
private static boolean wordCheck(String[] words) {
    if(words.length < 2) {
        return true; //check what to return if only 1 word is passed
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        String currentWord = words[i].toLowerCase();
        String previousWord = words[i - 1].toLowerCase();

        if(!currentWord.startsWith(previousWord.substring(
                previousWord.length() - 1))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

It just checks each word's beginning against its preceding word's ending.

```
wordCheck("Chocolate Elephant Toronto".split(" ")) //returns true
wordCheck("Chocolate Elephant oronto".split(" ")) //returns false
```

Remember to validate the words that you send to the method. The above doesn't ensure indexes are valid, nulls and 0-length strings can cause exceptions.